# Railo ORM Not Persisting To Datasource - But Where Is It Persisting To?

Tags: orm, coldfusion, railo

Here's some real strange stuff.  Railo 4.2.2 (latest/bleeding edge).  Create a user, persist, flush and then query the db via sql and ORM:

```
<cfset u = var user = new com.sharp.model.user.User({username: "admin", password: hash("p@ssw3rd"), isAdmin: true})>

<cfset entitySave( u )>
<cfset ormFlush()>
<cfquery name="foo">
    select *
    from user
</cfquery>
<cfdump var="#foo#" />
<cfdump var="#ormExecuteQuery('from User')#" />
```

And here's what I see:

[image]

What is up with that?  Reloading the page adds another one to the array, so it's saving it *somewhere*, but not in my dsn??

ORM settings from App.cfc?

```
this.datasource = 'rrm';
this.ormSettings = { cfclocation: ormPaths, logSQL: false, flushAtRequestend: false, eventHandling: true, saveMapping: false, dbCreate: 'update', secondaryCacheEnabled: false };
```

Comment: Something in Railo bleeding edge release was causing this (very strange) issue.  I rolled back the patches and it's working fine.

Comment: Todd, did you raise a bug for this? I'm seeing it too.

Comment: Ah, found it: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RAILO-3273

Comment: Tood, see my answer to your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27337983/fw-1-app-calling-onapplicationstart-on-every-request/27447340#27447340 The changes are being made within the ORM session hence you can see them, but are not being flushed to the DB. Definitely a regression bug. With other consquences too: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/railo/7OKejFpq4PA